# Slow Outlook email sends with Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We have an application that sends mail merge campaigns via Graph API. In the app, we keep track of the timings and benchmarks per campaign. We found that some of our users will run into an issue where their mail merge campaign is sending very slow sometimes. Normally for a campaign with about 1k recipients, the average send per email will be less than 1-2 seconds. But sometimes we get **averaging around 17-30 seconds per email send** with Graph API. For a total of 1k recipients, this is a long time to process a mail merge campaign. More often than not, this causes the total time for a mail merge campaign to finish between 2-4 hours. Note, it's not necessarily because of the number of emails / recipients. We've seen this happen when the recipients range from 500 to 2k even.

I'm not too sure whether the issue here is with Graph API or the user's mailbox throttling (sending limits). I suspect it's the prior because, often, users will resend the same campaign when they see that the first campaign is very slow. What ends up happening is that **the second campaign will actually finish very quickly**, even before the slow campaign has processed half of them.

It almost seems like the server processing my first set of Graph API requests is warming up. Is there any configuration that I can set in the API request that may help with this? I couldn't find anything in the documentation referencing this.

Has anyone else had experience with this issue? Is there some configuration that the tenant can adjust or review that may be a root cause of this?